# Google maps V2 android tiles do not show after a certain zoom level

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm new to Google maps. Why is is that when I'm trying to zoom in (either with controls or by tapping), after a - relatively high - zoom level the tiles stop loading and all I see is a pixelated view.

Here is my complete activity:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        System.out.println("Onresume");
        mapFragment.onResume();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng center = new LatLng(47.49801, 19.03991);

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(center).title("Marker"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(center));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use value required value for zoom laval

```
  mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mLocation, 5f));
```